# contract violation scheme logic

Tags: scheme, racket

I though calling a list and checking will it be even or odd would work this way.
It suppose to take a list [ 2 6 4 5] and check every element that is at a even position and print t or f. [2 #t 4 #f]. I know my try to do modulo on a list, that is probably causing the error. Is there way to check for the current list and check if it's even or odd.

```
modulo: contract violation
 expected: integer?
 given: '(2 3 4)
 argument position: 1st
other arguments...:

 (define (isEven E)
  (if(= (modulo E 2) 0) #t #f))

  (define (evenEE L)
   (if (or (null? L) (null? (cdr L)))
    L
    (cons (car L)
             (cons (isEven )
                   (evenEE (cddr L))
                   ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't applying the predicate correctly. In the definition of evenEE:

```
(define (evenEE L)
   (if (or (null? L) (null? (cdr L)))
    L
    (cons (car L)
             (cons (isEven )
                   (evenEE (cddr L))
                   ))))
```

You need to replace `(isEven )` with `(isEven (cadr L))`. That will call `isEven` with the second element in the list. Based on the error message you gave, I'm guessing you previously had it as `(isEven (cdr L))`. That would try to test whether the entire tail of the lest is even, which wouldn't make sense.

As an aside, the if form in `isEven` is redundant. You can replace

```
(define (isEven E)
  (if(= (modulo E 2) 0) #t #f))
```

with

```
(define (isEven E)
  (= (modulo E 2) 0))
```

So the whole program should look like this:

```
(define (isEven E)
  (= (modulo E 2) 0))

(define (evenEE L)
  (if (or (null? L) (null? (cdr L)))
    L
    (cons (car L)
          (cons (isEven (cadr L))
                (evenEE (cddr L))))))
```

Testing it out:

```
> (evenEE '(2 6 4 5))
'(2 #t 4 #f)
```

Comment: you are right, cdr would look at the entire list. Cadr would only look at the currentelement..